# cloning the controls

Tags: silverlight

I am designing a silverlight application in which i will have a rectangle control at the left side, when i click the rectangel and drag a copy of the rectangle control should be created and dragged and dropped in to the page.

Please can anyone help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I'm going to leave out the Drag-Drop stuff since this question seems mainly about the cloning aspect.

The tool needed is the `DataTemplate` class.  You place in a resource dictionary the set of items you want to clone each enclosed in a `DataTemplate`.   You can use `ContentPresenter` to display instances of these items in say stack panel on the left.  You can then use code to create instances of the template content and place them in say a `Canvas` on the right.

**Example.**

Xaml:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.CloningStuff"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
  >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Rectangle">
            <Rectangle Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="CornflowerBlue" Width="100" Height="75" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Rectangle" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Rectangle}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas x:Name="Surface" MouseLeftButtonDown="Surface_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.Column="1" Background="Wheat">

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code:-

```
public partial class CloningStuff : UserControl
{
    public CloningStuff()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Surface_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas target = (Canvas)sender;
        Point p = e.GetPosition(target);

        Rectangle r = (Rectangle)((DataTemplate)Resources["Rectangle"]).LoadContent();
        Canvas.SetLeft(r, p.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(r, p.Y);

        target.Children.Add(r);

    }
}
```

This shows using a `ContentPresenter` to display your rectangle.  In place of drag-dropping (for which there are plenty of examples of elsewhere) this code just creates a Clone of the rectangle whereever the user clicks in the Canvas.